# Google Analytics API throwing 500 Internal Server Error (Service Account) with certificate

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytic API to fetch data. I am fetching data from last 1 years without any issue. But, from yesterday, on server getting following error on API call : -

```
Google.GoogleApiRequestException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Backend Error [500] Errors [Message[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global] ] ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Another noticeable thing is when i got above error constantly on production server upon calling API. that time i have tried same API calls from my local machine/stage machine with same code and certificate and it is working fine every time.

Means right now I'm able to get all data with same code and service account on my local and stage.

Please find the code below:

```
 private static GaData executeDataQueryForCustomDimension(Analytics analytics, String profileId,Map reqMap)  {
      GaData gaData = new GaData();
      String startDate = (String) reqMap.get("fromDate");
      String toDate = (String) reqMap.get("toDate");
    try {
        gaData = analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, // Table Id.
                startDate, // Start date.2015-01-01
                toDate, // End date.2015-07-07
            "ga:visits") // Metrics.
            .setDimensions("ga:pagePath")
          .setMetrics("ga:timeOnPage")
          .setFilters("ga:pagePath!~^/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+/;ga:pagePath!@login;ga:pagePath!@admin;ga:pagePath!@.com;ga:pagePath!@p_p_id;ga:pagePath!@?;ga:pagePath!@blog;ga:pagePath!@add-review;ga:pagePath!@.html;ga:pagePath!@manufacturer/;ga:pagePath!@product-evaluations;ga:pagePath!@product;ga:pagePath!@request-more-info;ga:pagePath!@video/;ga:pagePath!@categories/")
            .setStartIndex(1)
          .setMaxResults(40000)
            .execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error getting data",e.getMessage());
    }

      return gaData;
  }
```

I have also tried exponential backoff (delay) to call API on server. but, that help me up to only 5 to 10 calls. But after that i have got same errors. & same thing is working on my local machine/stage every time.

I'm getting hits on dashboard of analytic which google provide but in error section whenever I call from production.

Please,let me know if anyone has idea about this issue & how to solve this issue.

Using below version of API,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev116-1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am the one who fires the call so.So there are no max call in seconds applies as I'm hitting server one per second or so while testing.

Comment: GaData ?? which version of the API are you using?   check your project on google developer console see what you have the request per sec rate set to max is 10 I think unless you are using v4 which it doesn't appear that you are max is higher.

Comment: Updated the question. Please check out.Please note that same code is working on stage and local.

Comment: Max you can request with the V3 is 10 requests a second you are trying to go to fast.  You are using exponential back off there is nothing more that you can do.

Comment: Try shortening the date range. and see if you still get the `5XX` error. It is better to make 10 requests that finish efficiently than 1 request that will timeout, as you are only allowed [10 failed requests per hour and 50 failed requests per day](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis_request_errors)

Comment: But same code same credential same certificate is working on stage and local

Comment: I have the exact same issue. No clue what is happening.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.This used to happen once every 3-4 days (out of the 6k-7K calls we make to the API everyday), however in the last 48 hours, the rate at which it happens has increased to about 2% of all requests.

Comment: I am getting it on every request I do for production only...not on local and stage.